# Inorder traversal of BST printing "%" at the end

Tags: java, debugging, binary-search-tree

I am trying to print the elements of binary search tree. The code runs normally for most of the part but it is printing "%" symbol at the end of execution every time. I am using inorder traversal. I tried using debugger but it seems the symbol is printed just before the program exits from the main function.

It would be helpful if you can point out why and when this happens.

**Output**

```
(base) ➜  Trees java Tree
3 10 11 12 %
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;

class Node{
    int key;
    Node left, right;

    Node(int key){
        this.key = key;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree{
    Node root;

    BinaryTree(){
        root = null;
    }

    BinaryTree(int key){
        root = new Node(key);
    }

    //Wrapper over recursive
    void push(int num) {
        push(num, this.root);
    }

    Node search(int query) {
        return search(query, this.root);
    }

    void inOrder() {
        inOrder(this.root);
    }

    Node search(int query, Node root) {
        if(root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if(root.key == query){
            return root;
        }else if(root.key > query){
            return search(query, root.left);
        }else{
            return search(query, root.right);
        }
    }

    void push(int num, Node root){
        if(this.root == null) {
            this.root = new Node(num);
        }else{
            if(num < root.key){
                if(root.left == null)
                    root.left = new Node(num);
                else
                    push(num, root.left);
            }else{
                if(root.right == null)
                    root.right = new Node(num);
                else
                    push(num, root.right);
            }
        }
    }

    void inOrder(Node node) {
        if(node == null)
            return;

        inOrder(node.left);
        System.out.print(node.key + " ");
        inOrder(node.right);
    }

}

class Tree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();

        tree.push(10);
        tree.push(3);
        tree.push(12);
        tree.push(11);
        tree.inOrder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the output with your code, I guess this may be a problem residing in your IDE.

Comment: @JerryChin I am using z shell (oh my zsh). Is it related to that? IDE is vs code.

Comment: I suggest you to do a simple hello world printing to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the terminal. It moves to the next line after exiting the program even though I have not used 'println" and prints "%" symbol while doing so. It works normally in default terminal. Thanks.